# boost::asio::deadline_timer doesn't wake up (stress scenario)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using a deadline_timer as an asynchronous event and I'm running into a situation where, after some time, the thread waiting on the event never seems to be woken up (despite more calls to `cancel()`).  I've been able to reproduce this using some sample code that I've pasted below; it's not exactly consistent but I have seen what I think is the same issue I'm experiencing.

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
timer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

int num_events = 0;
auto waiter = [&timer, &num_events](boost::asio::yield_context context) {
  while (true) {
    std::cout << "waiting on event" << std::endl;
    boost::system::error_code e;
    timer.async_wait(context[e]);
    std::cout << "got event (" << e << ")" << std::endl;
    ++num_events;
  }
};

boost::asio::spawn(io_service, std::move(waiter));
boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

for (auto i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
  timer.cancel();
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Am I doing something here that's unsupported and inadvertently hitting some race condition?  The error code from the `wait()` never looks troublesome (even on the very last time it's woken up before it never seems to again).  EDIT: I've also noticed the original bug on 3 different platforms (Windows, Mac and Linux) but the above test I've been using to reproduce has been on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadline_timer object is not threadsafe.

You're canceling it from another thread than the one that's posting the async_wait. This means the calls can race.

I'm not sure how this can completely inhibit the callback, in your sample. It seems to me that the program should /just/ quit because the tight loop to 500000 finishes quickly (doing many redundant cancels that never get processed, because the coroutine would e.g. not even have posted the new async_wait).

So maybe you mean, "why don't I get 500000 events".

---

### UPDATE

After the comment, here's a trivial transformation that shows how you are gonna be fine calling members on the timer *from within an actor*. Note: this critically hinges on the idea that the `io_service` is run from a single thread only!

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::thread;
using boost::asio::io_service;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service     io_service;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
    timer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

    boost::atomic_bool shutdown(false);

    int num_events = 0;
    auto waiter = [&timer, &num_events, &shutdown](boost::asio::yield_context context) {
        while (!shutdown) {
            std::cout << "waiting on event" << std::endl;

            boost::system::error_code e;
            timer.async_wait(context[e]);

            std::cout << "got event (" << e.message() << ")" << std::endl;
            ++num_events;
        }
    };

    boost::asio::spawn(io_service, std::move(waiter));
    boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    for (auto i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        io_service.post([&timer, i]{ 
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                timer.cancel(); 
            });
    }

    io_service.post([&]{ 
            shutdown = true;
            timer.cancel();
        });

    thread.join();

    std::cout << "Check: " << num_events << " events counted\n";
}
```

---

Also, it looks like you just wanted to signal a background task. As given you can simplify the program like:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/094b718beef92dc9)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::thread;
using boost::asio::io_service;

int main() {
    io_service svc;
    int num_events = 0;

    auto work = boost::make_shared<io_service::work>(svc); // keep svc running
    boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &svc));

    for (auto i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
        svc.post([&num_events,i]{
                std::cout << "got event (" << i << ")" << std::endl;
                ++num_events;
                });
    }

    work.reset();
    thread.join();

    std::cout << "Check: " << num_events << " events counted\n";
}
```

This *does* print all 500000 events:

```
got event (0)
got event (1)
got event (3)
...
got event (499998)
got event (499999)
Check: 500000 events counted
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...I don't actually care about getting every single event...this was just a way to reproduce the scenario that the 'waiter' stops getting woken up after some amount of time.  Unfortunately the post method won't work for me; in my scenario it's basically a reader and writer from/to a buffer, and, if the buffer is empty, the reader will asynchronously wait on the event that there's data (the call is made in the middle of the method and suspends using a yield_context, which I'd like to have to keep things 'linear') which the writer fires whenever it writes.

Comment: @bbaldino Well. Did you notice that I explain in my answer why it can't work the way you wrote it? IOW: the answer is there, just apply the principles in the way you wanted it. _The fact that I went on to deconstruct your sample into something equivalent but simpler, shouldn't detract from the answer.

Comment: (I was just noting you were using the timer as a make-shift barrier among "threads". There's simply better ways to do that. If you have good reasons to use that coro, then make sure you cancel the timer (~"fire the event") ***from within another Asio actor***).

Comment: @bbaldino I've updated the answer with **[the simplest way you could fix your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/483e98f32fac6871)** so that it actually works (and completes; infinite timers don't usually finish).

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  I didn't see in there an explanation was to why the waiter would be woken up fine for many iterations and then stop alltogether (I saw why it wouldn't get every single event, but I didn't considered that 'broken' for my use case)--so I'm still curious if there's some internal state to deadline_timer that gets corrupted in some way with that usage (not just inconsistent wake ups).  That being said, thanks a lot for your suggestion on working around it; it seems like a good plan.  I'll give it a try and see if it works!

Comment: I wish there was a way to do an async event that wouldn't require knowledge of a single thread or a strand for this, but I guess that's not so bad.

Comment: @bbaldino I see the reason for the missed wake-ups being that the loop (0..500000) completes, leaving the destructor of `io_service` stuck waiting for a pending `deadline_timer`. But of course, the wait is infinite...

Comment: ah, I see...I should've been more descriptive about the result I was seeing.  In the test code I posted above, for a while there are mixed prints between the event counter (printing "i") and the prints about "waiting for event" and "got event".  However, after some amount of time, the "i" prints continue and no more "waiting for event"/"got event" prints are seen.  Unless this is some odd console print buffering (though I would expect both to be buffered equally, so the prints should continue to be mixed?) I assumed this was due to the timer no longer being woken up

Comment: @bbaldino Don't sell yourself short: Observation > assumption. However, the reason for this is moot: using deadline_timer from different threads without synchronization presents a data race, and all such programs exhibit [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). :)

Comment: Haha thanks...and changing the usage to be within the same thread seemed to have fixed the problem!  Undefined behavior strikes again... :)